# Refreshing Access Token for Fitbit

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I am integrating fitbit in my application and I don't want the user to redirect every time to SafariViewController to get the access token, for that i am storing the Access Token, but after 24 hours the Access Token is expiring.

In the API of fitbit [Fitbit OAuth 2.0](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/) there is a parameter `expires_in` which is used to define the expiration time of Access Token, In that parameter i am passing `31536000` for 1 year, but after that also the Access Token is expiring in 24 hours, and after that i have to redirect the user to SafariViewController.

So, is there any workaround so that i don't have to redirect user to SafariViewController, any methods through which i will refresh the token in background, something like that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers !!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need to set any `expires_in` value to your access_token. The expire of access_token is checked in the fitbit server not in your server. So by setting the `expires_in` will not work. Instead you will get are `refresh_token` along with your acess_token after Fitbit authorization.By calling the

```
 $result=$fitbit_object->getRefreshtoken(YOUR_REFRSH_TOKEN);
```

The result will contains new access_token and refresh_token.Store/update  them in you db. So when you want to use the aceess_token , you can use the new refresh_token to refresh your access_token . Its simply works for me.

Comment: Yeah, i have tried that and it worked for me also, Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You saved my day Prakash..even I was looking for this solution

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks guys.

Comment: @PrakashP it gives very strange error to me, see below {"errors":[{"errorType":"invalid_grant","message":"Refresh token invalid: c28e8f226845e7bef3b9db85162ecb02e001e2a47e4babc8934cb1d3addc7412. Visit https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2 for more information on the Fitbit Web API authorization process."}],"success":false}

Comment: @Hiren Gujarati:- The error is occurred when your refresh token is used more than once. Please use refresh token for once and update the new refresh token for next use

Comment: @PrakashP thanks, yes it occurred due to i am using open source from github to authenticate for oauth2 and manage everything which has multiple refresh attempt. As i changed to refresh manually, it started working fine. Thank you :)

Comment: @HirenGujarati :)